I got a error while pip install flash-attn throwing error

enter code hereI am currently trying to install
'microsoft/Florence-2-large' model and following the documentation
provided here on its github page. When running pip install
flash-attn --no-build-isolation I am thrown this error:


Collecting flash_attn   Using cached flash_attn-2.5.9.post1.tar.gz
(2.6 MB)   Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting
requirements to build wheel ... error   error:
subprocess-exited-with-error
     × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\manik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py",
line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\manik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py",
line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\manik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py",
line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\manik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rifgc3eo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\manik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rifgc3eo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\manik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rifgc3eo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
line 497, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\manik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rifgc3eo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py",
line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │
exit code: 1 ╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip.



This might help.. No module named packaging

It quite literally states that it needs a module named packaging.
Try:
pip install packaging


I had the same issue. Above solution worked
